# How do i fill an objects attributes dynamically?

Tags: php

I am trying to save an object with a variable amount of "cols". The number of cols is equal to the number of headers. This is how the code looked before:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sub = new Sub();
    $sub->product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

    $sub->col1 = $_POST['col1'];
    $sub->col2 = $_POST['col2'];
    $sub->col3 = $_POST['col3'];
    $sub->col4 = $_POST['col4'];
    $sub->col5 = $_POST['col5'];
    $sub->col6 = $_POST['col6'];
    $sub->col7 = $_POST['col7'];
    $sub->col8 = $_POST['col8'];
    $sub->col9 = $_POST['col9'];
    $sub->col10 = $_POST['col10'];
    $sub->col11 = $_POST['col11'];
    $sub->col12 = $_POST['col12'];
    $sub->col13 = $_POST['col13'];
    $sub->col14 = $_POST['col14'];
    $sub->col15 = $_POST['col15'];
```

This is how I want it to look:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sub = new Sub();
    $sub->product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($headers as $header){
        $i++ ;
        $sub->col.$i = $_POST['col'.$i];
    }
```

How do I pass the variable $i into the object's attributes? $sub->(col.$i) ? $sub->(col{$i}) ? Please help me figure this out =) Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sub = new Sub();
$sub->product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
for($i = 1; $i <= count($headers); ++$i)
   $sub->{'col' . $i} = $_POST['col' . $i];
```

But, this is *really* not the way that the columns should be stored in the `Sub` object, you should use an array:

```
$sub->columns = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= count($headers); ++$i) {
    $sub->columns[] = $_POST['col' . $i];
}
```

Comment: I agree, column type should be an array.

Comment: Now I have to work on passing the $sub->columns to my class and writing a function that pulls the header count and adds/drops fields from the tables based on the header count...right?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `{}` :

```
$sub->{'col' . $i} = ...
```

Comment: [This page](http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php) implies that you can also treat the object as an associative array and just do `$sub['col' . $i] = ...`, is that the case?  If so than I think its syntax is slightly cleaner/more intuitive.

Comment: Objects are not arrays, and you cannot do that *(except if your class is extending the ArrayObject class)* ;;; note that the page you linked to is part of the documentation of SDO *(and, isn't part of the manual that's about object oriented programming)*

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I didn't know if the syntax was even possible. I don't think I'll use the $sub->{'col' . $i} over Slik and Dae's suggestion for the finished app - but for testing, your syntax might be a faster way to accomplish things. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$field = "col$i";
$sub->$field = "whatver"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer a setter method.

```
class Sub {

  public function set($attribute, $value) {
    $this->$attribute = $value;
  }

}
```

Now you can do:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $sub->set($key, $value)
}
```

Or without the loose coupling:

```
$i = 1;
while($value = $_POST['col' . $i]) {
  $sub->set('col' . $i, $value);
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around this, I don't really understand how this works - but then again I'm a noob and not familiar with setters.